# Getting JSON data from a .java file

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I have a Java Method, in a class called by a Java Servlet, that returns an Array of JSONObjects. For example, if I loop through the array in a standard for loop, each object is printed as you would expect a JSONObject to appear.

I am struggling to understand how to use the .getJSON() Jquery method to get this data. Somehow, I need to get these JSONObjects to be called by this method, so I can populate a DataTable (using AJAX).

```
{"lastName":"doe","requestVar":3,"name":" John","rqTime":"1402600668949"} 
{"lastName":"doe","requestVar":4,"name":" Jane","rqTime":"1402677126117"}
```

Currently, the only answers I can find are when people use the .getJSON method on a .JSON file; is there any way for me to .getJSON from a .java file?

Comment: Do you have the servlet code?

Answer (score 0):

In the .getJSON method, you can call a URL. So make a servlet call in this URL. Make that servlet return the JSON Array as string. In Javascript, get the output and use it.

Comment: Use your own servlet mapping,                                       $.getJSON( "<serveltmapping>", function( data ) {
var items = [];
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
});
$( "<ul/>", {
"class": "my-new-list",
html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "body" );
});